# Jump/Goto last "running" breakpoint line

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.4 and debugging Java. I have set a couple of breakpoints and that works fine. I run to a line and then it stops. I can inspect and all.

**BUT** If you I choose to enter a class or more I loose where the breakpoint actually was, that is where the debugger has stopped. I have to keep track of it myself and scroll back and stuff.

I just want to go back to where the last breakpoint was ( that is where the debugger has stopped )

How can I do that?

Thanks!

=== EDIT === 
I know that I can watch the call stack but nothing there is highlighted so it is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of such a possibility.

However, depending on the number of active breakpoints you are using, maybe the "Breakpoints" view can help. Here you can see all breakpoints you have defined. If you make a doubleclick on an entry, Eclipse jumps to the corresponding source location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the breakpoint view is possible to use but this is as you stated yourself, not helpful when there are many breakpoints ( some of which might be disabled ).